# How to draw N -times heptagon shapes not on top of each others, using Python Turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

below code draw shapes in the same place and on top of each other. is there any possible way to draw the shapes separately ??

```
   
import turtle

tegan = turtle.Turtle()

turtle.fillcolor('grey')

turtle.begin_fill()


numbers = int(input('number of 50 Pence: '))
print(numbers)

length = 100  
degrees = 51.42857
angle = 40

def draw_heptagon(tegan, length, numbers, angle):

    for i in range(numbers):
        for x in range(7):
            turtle.forward(length)
            turtle.left(degrees)
        turtle.right(angle)

draw_heptagon(tegan, length, numbers, angle)

turtle.end_fill()
turtle.done()
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: Write an algorithm in Python asking the user to input an integer, and draw that amount of fifty pence piece shapes (heptagon) using Tegan the Turtle. You can draw the seven sides as straight lines, and there is no need to fill in the detail on the coins.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Please [edit] your question and post **what you have tried so far to solve the problem**. The current code just draws `n` heptagons on top of each other. What have you tried to spread them out?

Comment: i have try to add coordination(x,y) but unfortunately, it gives the same results

Comment: OK, so [edit] your question and post the code you tried. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial, code-writing, or homework service. "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Comment: i have add my last version of code.

Comment: what do you mean by draw them separately? can you draw a picture of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: if the user enters number = 4, I need to get 4 separate heptagons.

Comment: After drawing one, you can penup(), move the turtle some distance away, then pendown() again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the pen somewhere else:

```
import turtle

tegan = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.fillcolor('grey')
turtle.begin_fill()

numbers = int(input('number of 50 Pence: '))

length = 50  
degrees = 51.42857
angle = 40

def draw_heptagon(tegan, size, numbers, angle):

    for i in range(numbers):
        for x in range(7):
            turtle.forward(length)
            turtle.left(degrees)
        turtle.right(angle)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(length * 2)
        turtle.pendown()

draw_heptagon(tegan, length, numbers, angle)
turtle.end_fill()
turtle.done()
```